# How to get the text value of the style attribute?

Tags: html, css, getelementbyid, inline-styles

I need to display CSS style of an element exactly as I have defined it in its inline style. For example, I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div
  id="1"
style="background: 
radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0,
  salmon,
  rgba(255,0,0,0) 10px),
radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%,
  salmon,
  rgba(255,0,0,0) 10px);
background-size: 10px 10px;
"> </div>
```

I want to get a STRING that looks like this:

```
radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0,
  salmon,
  rgba(255,0,0,0) 10px),
radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%,
  salmon,
  rgba(255,0,0,0) 10px);
background-size: 10px 10px;
```

I'm not trying to change styles, I just need a string of an inline style. I have many different elements with different styles.
I'm using `document.getElementById(1).style.cssText` method to achieve what I want, but it doesn't work. In Firefox I get a lot of different properties with it (for example, `background-origin`, `background-clip`, etc.), so the result looks like this:

```
background-color: black;
background-position: 0% 0%, 0% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat, repeat;
background-attachment: scroll, scroll;
background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0px, salmon, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 10px), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%, salmon, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 10px);
background-size: 10px 10px;
background-origin: padding-box, padding-box;
background-clip: border-box, border-box;
```

while in Chrome `background-size` gets removed. What method should I use to get inline style in string format exactly how it is defined in my inline style?

Comment: The behavior you see in Firefox is due to the browser explicitly listing all the default values for background-related properties. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment indicates that for `background-attachment` for example `scroll, scroll` is the default. This therefore should not have any influence on the effect of your set properties.

Comment: Thank you, I know it doesn't have any influence, but I don't want it listed in the output string. Since the properties vary from element to element, I can't ask for the ones I want. The only criteria is that they are listed in the inline style.

Comment: Why not `document.getElementById(1).getAttribute("style")`?

Comment: Because the same happens as with cssText.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I ran some experiments:

As I already touched upon in my comment, `background` (and `border`, ...) is a shorthand property that can set several properties in one go.

First: Firefox.
When changing the style attribute value of an element using the `elem.style.cssText` property, Firefox will unpack all of the properties `background` can set, including their implicit defaults. This means that, as you have seen, you get a bunch of properties like `background-attachment` and `background-repeat` in the attribute string. The behavior of your code is not influenced by that, the properties will be applied like you expect as long as you put `background` first.

Chrome behaves a little bit less like what you would expect. In the process of parsing the new input you provided for the style attribute, it will expand the properties explicitly and implicitly set by the `background` shorthand and override any other changes to the background-related stuff that comes afterwards with them. Peculiarly, this error only seems to impact the JavaScript API, the image renders as expected. This behavior is most likely a bug in Chrome, so feel free to file it as such!

There are two fixes that work in both browsers and produce the expected behavior:

1. You are trying to set the background to a gradient in the first property. CSS considers gradients images, so the right non-shorthand property for that would be `background-image`. This disables all the *smart* browser behavior around shorthands, so you should be good with

   ```js
   document.getElementById("your-id").style.cssText = "background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0, salmon, rgba(255,0,0,0) 10px), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%, salmon, rgba(255,0,0,0) 10px); background-size: 10px 10px;"
   ```
2. Use another API. The usual way to change styles in JavaScript is to change the value of the relevant key in the style object. These values also end up in the style attribute but you save the browser a bit of parsing work (should even be a tiny bit faster). Doing what you want to do would look like this:

   ```js
   let e = document.getElementById("your-id");
   e.style.background = "radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0, salmon, rgba(255,0,0,0) 10px), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%, salmon, rgba(255,0,0,0) 10px)";
   e.style.backgroundSize = "10px 10px";
   ```

Hope that was useful, have a nice day!

Comment: Was this helpful to you? If so, please consider to mark the answer as 'accepted' using the checkmark button

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think I didn't explain it clearly though - I'm not trying to change the style, but just to get a string of the style. So although I know that all the attached properties will not change the style itself, they will change the string - and I'm not sure if I can change all the 'background" property to 'background-image'. That is why it will also not work in Chrome, since that behaviour is connected of them removing unneccessary css properties (if you have 'background', you don't really need 'background-size' - although you do for practical reasons)...

Comment: ...so it is not a bug. Thank you very much for taking the time and willingness to help! I gave you an upvote, but it doesn't show, since I'm new here.